# Problema al alinear elementos flotantes

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Mi problema pasa porque no logró adaptar el contenido float en una caja. Básicamente, tengo un *ul* con 6 *li* cada uno con su respectivo *img* y *p*. Mi objetivo es que se posicionen 2 *li* por línea cuando la resolución mínima sea de 468px y 3 *li* cuando sea de 768px. Cada uno de estos *li* deberían tener separación entre si.

[image: Floats no se adaptan a la box]

**CODIGO CSS**

```css
.lista-invitados li{
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
  .lista-invitados li {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .lista-invitados li {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}

.invitado {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.invitado img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

> El problema en cuestión es que el media query de 768px tome el 33.3% para cada *li* y que entren 3 por línea. No dos como me salen a mi y con ese espacio sin rellenar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomiendo que:

- Trabajes este diseño mediante el módulo [CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/)
- De manera que el contenedor podrá mover a sus elementos internos sobre un *grid bidimensional*
- Podemos dar de manera inicial un número determinado de columnas de esta forma:

  ```
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  ```
- Posterior según cada media query podemos replantear ese acomodo únicamente indicando el número de columnas deseas
- Te puedes evitar el dilema de los porcentajes si manejas las dimensiones mediante la unidad de medida [fr](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#fr-unit)

Quedando así:

```html
    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .listado {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      }
      .listado-elementos {
        border: 1px solid;
        list-style: none;
      }
      
      @media screen and (min-width: 468px) {
        .listado {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        }
      }
      
      @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .listado {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        }
      }
    </style>
    <ul class="listado">
      <li class="listado-elementos">1</li>
      <li class="listado-elementos">2</li>
      <li class="listado-elementos">3</li>
      <li class="listado-elementos">4</li>
      <li class="listado-elementos">5</li>
      <li class="listado-elementos">6</li>
    </ul>
```

Ahora para dar un espacio entre los elementos, puedes valerte de `grid-gap` a nivel de la regla CSS para el contenedor así:

```
.listado {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
 }
```

De esta manera no dependerías de hacer flotantes a los elementos.